# Where/how to save the star image(s) for this star-rating tutorial?

Tags: html, css, image, directory-structure, rating-system

I'm a relative newcomer to HTML/CSS trying to implement this star-rating tutorial: http://www.dillerdesign.com/css/cookbook/component_star_rater.html

The text and hovers are functioning, but the star images are not showing up.  From what I understand, I should only need to use the one image, called "img/star_rate.gif", is that correct?  If so, where should I store the image?  Do I need to create a new folder called "img" in my directory tree to store the image?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes maybe.  The `img/` part of the path is specifying a sub-directory.  If you take that part out you don't need the directory.

Comment: Thanks!  Where should I store the image itself?  I've tried putting it in the HTML parent directory, and the css parent directory, with no luck...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, create a folder called `img` and place your `star_rate.gif` inside that folder. That's what the `/` means.

Comment: Thank you!  Where should I store the folder in the directory tree?  In the parent folder of the CSS? or parent of HTML?  I tried both and neither seems to be working--elsewhere?

Comment: Sounds strange that neither of them are working. I usually place my image folder in the `HTML` root folder, so I'm guessing the author to the website did the same. Try again and double check names and filepaths.